# I get "Remote computer is not available" (MessageQueueException) when trying to read queue of remote server

Tags: c#, msmq

**I am trying to reach into and read the private queues of a remote server.**

I have tried this locally with success:

```
MessageQueue[] QueueList = MessageQueue.GetPrivateQueuesByMachine(".");

foreach(MessageQueue queueItem in QueueList)
{
    Console.WriteLine(queueItem.Path);
}
```

And i have tried this pointing at the remote server with no success:

```
MessageQueue[] QueueList = MessageQueue.GetPrivateQueuesByMachine(@"FormatName:DIRECT=OS:XXX.XX.X.XXX");

foreach(MessageQueue queueItem in QueueList)
{
    Console.WriteLine(queueItem.Path);
}
```

also tried with no success

```
var queue = new MessageQueue(@"FormatName:DIRECT=OS:XXX.XX.X.XXX\Private$\test-queue");
Console.WriteLine(queue.GetAllMessages().Count());
```

I want to get the list of private queues on the remote server.
(and count the messages in the queues)